# Closing a PR in IBM Maximo 5.2

Tags: maximo

There are some PR (purchase requestion's) that are showing  `hisoryflag='N'`
While I'm executing `select * from PR where historyflag='N'`,but I need to change it to 'Y' by force to close all related records to those PR's

Please tell how to force close all the related PR's

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please Provide More Details...
You Want Database query or any Operation UI Level.

By Default in Maximo PR Application out-of box.
History Flag sets 'N' in appBean in "initializeApp()" Method.

In PR application when status change to 'CANCEL'/'CLOSE' the History Flag sets to 'Y'.
.
.
that way cancel/ closed status related PR do not appear in the PR List Tab.